# Simple, cheap solution to photograph an pallet from 3 positions

Tags: remote, studio-setup, camera

I am looking fo the most simple/cheap solution to take 3 photo's of a pallet.
The pallet must be photographed from 3 sides. 
It can be a setup with 3 simple smartphones, which can take a photo remotely via bluetooth, or a cable or something. Or a simple (action?)camera, with WiFi.

If possible, the photo's should be automatically uploaded to a platform like Dropbox, or Google Drive.

In the process the operator places the pallet on a specific place, presses 3 buttons, at one location (not walking to the 3 camera's itself) and then goes on with the pallet.

Who can help me finding the right solution?

Comment: This feels a bit broad for this site. But what you describe can probably be put together with downloaded software and 3 wi-fi enabled mobiles. But you need to break this problem down into pieces because what you have described is an open-ended start of an idea that go off in any direction. First, get one phone triggering on some signal from somewhere. Then proceed from there.

Comment: vtc b/c This seems like an industrial application for which there are existing turn-key solutions.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a serious system integrator not a free online forum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A [Rapsberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) with:

- 3 USB webcams
- The `cheese` or `fswebcam` utilities (ffmpeg could also be an option) that takes still pictures using a webcam
- A button that triggers a script as desccribed [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Trigger-a-Webcam-with-a-button-and-Raspberry-Pi/)
- A script that calls `cheese`/`fswebcam` on the three cameras, and uploads the pics

The main cost is going to be a proper fixture to mount the USB cameras, as well a proper lighting.